# Wrap collection attribute with object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I've got a class structure like that:

[image]

(Its important to have `employee` wrapped with `Staff` object within `Employer`.)

And my DB structure looks like:

[image]

How can I map this class structure to this DB with Hibernate or JPA?

Comment: With xml or annotations.

Comment: @nikpon hello captain!

Comment: Hi, what a tool used to draw that diagrams. Also I'd like to know how they called.

Comment: @nikpon its class diagram and entity relationship diagram. Most of UML modeling tools can draw them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Employer`: annotate it with `@Entity`.

`Staff` annotate with `@Embeddable` and the list within it, annotate with `@OneToMany` and @JoinColumn(columnName="employee_id").

For the Ids use the e.g `@Column(name=employee_id)` annotation to set the column name.